# Remove certain styles from css when printing

Tags: html, css, printing, media

I am going about recreating a document in HTML. Thai is all up and running my issue now is i would like to print the page once it has been generated however i would like to remove some of the css styling applied to the display view. I have this so far...

```
.containerouter {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:21cm;
    height:29.7cm;
    padding-left:1.7cm;
    padding-right:1.7cm;
    padding-bottom:1.7cm;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -4px 2px 22px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -moz-box-shadow: -4px 2px 22px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    box-shadow: -4px 2px 22px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}

    @media print{.no-print, .no-print *{display: none !important;}}

<div class="containerouter no-print" media="print"> CONTENT NESTED INSIDE THIS DIV NEEDS TO BE PRINTED </div>
```

Basically i would like to remove the shadow properties without removing the sizing format already applied.
What is currently happening is all of the content is disappearing when print is clicked

Answer (score 8):

There is a media class for adding classes when printing:

```
@media print {
   [CSS only shown when printing]
}
```

if you want to remove some css styles you can do it like this:

```
@media print {
     .containerouter {
         box-shadow: none;
     }
}
```

You just need to declare the @media print after you define the class so that your media class get higher specificity.

Comment: "after you define the class" ... Exactly what I was doing wrong! Thanks!

Comment: @Broper this is so easy to do when use link more then one stylesheet in your html document.

Comment: Yes. One stylesheet was optimal for my case though, it was specifically for a page in a site that's sole purpose was to be printed, so it already had its own styling.